# How to prevent Rider from auto opening ASP.NET Core WebApp in browser after every run?

Tags: asp.net-core, settings, rider, jetbrains-rider

I am creating WebApp in Rider and I always have one (or more) window in browser opened with my App.
And then when I make some change and rerun Application, Rider opens another tab in browser.

I hope it can be disabled.
I looked for answer but couldn't find anything.

Every solution I found was about Visual Studio, but I couldn't find similar one in Rider.

Comment: Have you considered re-building an app instead of re-running?

Comment: Sorry for long time without answer.
I would rather avoid that because rider gives me warning:
"Build might fail as some files may be locked by an active run/debug session"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn it off in `Properties\launchSettings.json`, e.g.:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:46186",
      "sslPort": 44347
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "ASP.NETCoreWebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false, <---- THIS
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7104;http://localhost:5171",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false, <--- THIS
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then confirm this change in `Run`->`Edit Configuration...`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this saves me a lot of irritation.

Comment: it did not work for me. Browser still opens when I try to debug. Rider 2023.1